# cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack static web page failing to deploy on BlueMix Devops

Tags: devops-services

I have a simple static web site project on GitHub. I've created a pipeline that does a "Simple" build and deploy. The deploy log file shows the following "less than informative" error:

```
Preparing to start the job...
Cloning the 'master' branch from repo 'https://github.com/FlatBallFlyer/ssgpp.git'
Repository successfully cloned
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Using manifest file /home/pipeline/424009fc-100d-4068-9a23-3dde2271cba4/manifest.yml

Using stack cflinuxfs2...
OK
Creating app ssgpp in org Mike.Storey@us.ibm.com / space ssgpp as Mike.Storey@us.ibm.com...
OK

Using route ssgpp.mybluemix.net
Binding ssgpp.mybluemix.net to ssgpp...
OK

Uploading ssgpp...
FAILED
Error processing app files: Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 0, message: 

Finished: FAILED
```

The manifest.yml from the git project is simply:

```
applications:
- name: ssgpp
  memory: 64M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  host: ssgpp
  stack: cflinuxfs2
```

This is a giga-pixel panoramic photo web app that contains A LOT of files - about 1.5gb of images. I'm not sure if I'm blowing the top off of a BlueMix limit or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you reached the limit of your plan in BlueMix. 
BTW, 1.5GB isn't a reasonable size - for me - to deploy an app. You'll always send the files when doing a simple bugfix? I'd suggest you to move your images to another service, dedicated to store files, such [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I currently host at AWS S3 and was looking for a way to host on BlueMix - so Cloudinary is not the alternative I was looking for.

Comment: But you'll continue hosting your app on BlueMix, just the images goes to Cloudinary. Separating it will avoid a lot of headache with lack of space and deploy time. Good luck!

Comment: The images are generated by a panoramic viewer utility - and must be in a specific directory structure relative to the javascript and main page - How would this differ from hosting the images on GitHub for deployment to blue mix using the static-file buildpack? If the content is all static, it would seem like the Cloudinary solution would not need a BlueMix component to serve the content publicly.